# TF50608: Unable to retrieve information for security object - Unable to get into Collection administrative panel

Tags: c#, tfs

I was adding a project for someone in a specific collection in TFS 2012.
When I try to access the admin panel for the collection.  I get the error

TF50608: Unable to retrieve information for security object $PROJECT:vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/d375fabc-d16f-4031-8c5d-e3250e758864, it does not exist.

Everything else in the collection seems to be working (project pages, project admin pages etc).

The cause of the issue was probably our database issue that we had a few weeks ago.  The dba had to repair the TFS collection database.

---

I've tried a few things from what I've googled

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2a9817d7-e2b9-4036-bbf1-3e9abb78ab91/error-tf50608-unable-to-retrieve-information-for-security-object?forum=tfsworkitemtracking
- I invoked the StampWorkitemCache webservice on the server.
- Nothing really happened.
- I tried deleting the cache on my work station
- I went on the server and tried to delete the file under (probably 3gb's worth)
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Version Control Proxy_tfs_data

Comment: 1st: What so you mean by repair? If the DBA changed the database in any way you are in an unsupported state! You need to rollback to a backup before the change and call MS support.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly the dba did.  My best guest is somethig like this - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11233/sql-server-2008-r2-suspect-mode-how-to-repair

Comment: If that is all you are probably good, but that it ocured at all is suspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a support call.

So here's to add some information about the TFS & database issue we had.

Our configuration database & 1 collection was repaired with DBCC checkdb
but one collection had to be restored from a 2 day old back up.

In that 2 day difference, we lost a project that had been created.  That project name was only visible when you connected to the collection with Team Explorer (the screen where you have a listing of all available project with checkboxes beside them).  (It wouldn't show up on the website nor the source control explorer).

So the configuration database had an entry for the project (see table tbl_CatalogResource) but the collection database had no knowledge of the project (see table tbl_project & tbl_projects.

We were able to solve the issue by doing the following

- Recreate the project using VS2013 with the same name (Had to run it twice).

Why twice?  the first time, it gave a TF error that disappeared (didn't think of writing down the error code).  I ran it again to write down the error but then the process worked.

So hopefully this will help someone with the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error that should occur. You need to raise a support request with Microsoft to get it fixed. Do not edit the database in any way or you will be unsupportable.

Comment: Thanks, I'll write something up on the msdn board then.

Comment: I would raise a PSS on support.microsoft.com